# Mercurial Eclipse: See changes outside of project directories

Tags: eclipse, scala, egit, mercurialeclipse

I created my multi-project Scala build with two project directories, both subdirectories of the repository root directory, due to the statement [here](https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse/wiki/Using-sbteclipse) that "If your parent projects are merely folders aggregating sub projects, then using skipParents := true will ease importing all your sub projects into Eclipse using the Import Wizard like described above by reducing the number of necessary "runs"."

However, Mercurial Eclipse cannot see changes to files outside the two projects (e.g. `project/Build.scala`), even when I press F5 to refresh Eclipse's view of the filesystem, and this causes me endless annoyances, especially when - as now - I am trying to partially revert some changes.

How can I make Mercurial Eclipse see the changes?

"Switch to git" might be an acceptable answer - if EGit works better in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

In **MercurialEclipse** right click on the project and select **Team >> Refresh Status**. The change will then show in the Synchronize view when synchronizing the nested project.

Comment: Unfortunately this no longer works for me - I reported a bug [here](https://bitbucket.org/mercurialeclipse/main/issue/445/synchronize-view-cannot-see-contents-of).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Mercurial(Eclipse) user, but maybe you should use `skipParents := false` so you can import the root project into Eclipse. That means that you have to run the import wizard twice, once for the root project and once for the two subprojects.

Answer (score 1):

In EGit, changed files outside of the workspace are also shown in the [Git Staging view](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Git_Staging_View). Because Eclipse does not know about these files, you will have to manually press the refresh button in the *Git Staging* view to make the changes visible.

In case you want to edit such a file from within Eclipse, open the [Git Repositories view](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Managing_Repositories), navigate to the file in the *Working Directory* node and double-click it. This will open an editor for the file.